# How to set threshold of SlowQueryReport interceptor of Tomcat in Spring Boot properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We need to configure `SlowQueryReport` Tomcat interceptor in our Spring boot application, specifically  [`threshold`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport) value in properties files. Couldn't find anything on the web. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the old syntax (see below, note the given `threshold`) in the configuration file and it worked:

```
spring.datasource:
  tomcat.jdbc-interceptors: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=10);any.other.tomcat.Interceptor
```